# Use specific currency symbol in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format, unicode

'₴' is a currency sign used for the Ukrainian Hryvnia. It's in Unicode since 2004.
I want to use it in spreadsheets as a sign for money values, but Google Spreadsheets doesn't understand it as a number if I add it after or before my value in the cell.
How do I make Google Spreadsheets understand it's currency and display it as a number in my desired format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Spreadsheets uses 'грн.' to identify hryvnia. To use the currency [Google tells us](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56470) we need to:

1. Select the range of cells you'd like to format or modify.
2. Click the **123** toolbar icon.
3. Select the number, date, or currency format you'd like to apply to the range of cells.

You can also add Custom Currencies (like ₴) using the **123** menu as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Type in the currency you want:

[image]

and you will be able to select them:

[image]